# Сondition for the attribute

Tags: attributes

I Have next question, i added attubute:

```
<?php
                    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
                    $setup->addAttribute('customer', 'vat', array(
                    'label'     => 'VAT',
                    'type'      => 'varchar',
                    'input'     => 'text',
                    'visible'   => true,
                    'required'  => false,
                    'position'  => 1,
                    ));
                    $eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
                    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'vat');
                    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit'));  //enable all action
                    $attribute->save();
                    ?>
```

now i need add condition: if the attribute is empty, print the value NO in vat field

how i can do this better?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get customer attribute value and check if empty like this ,

```
$customer_id = 2; // your customer id
$customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id); 
$val = $customerObj->getData('vat');

if(empty($val)) {
//your stuff here
}
else {
//your stuff here
}
```